# react native delay state why it takes 700ms-1sec?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a Product Card. You can choose a color.

So I have also a Color Component.

If you choose a color then I set a state for selectedColor like this:

```
setSelectedColor(color);
```

So but I have also send the current color to the main Component (Product Card).

So I also use useEffect if selectedColor was pressed or changed like this:

```
const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState('');
const handleChooseColor = color => {
  setSelectedColor(color);
};

useEffect(() => {
 // Send it to main Component (prop: onPress)
 onPress(selectedColor);
}, [selectedColor]);
```

So now I set in the main component also a setSelectedColor.
Product Card.

```
...
<Choose_Color onPress={color => setSelectedColor(color)} data={dataColor} />
```

Choose_color fullcode:

```
import React, { useState, memo, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import pure from 'recompose/pure';

const Choose_Color = memo(({ data, onPress }) => {
  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState(null);
  const handlePress = color => {
    setSelectedColor(color);
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    onPress(selectedColor);
  }, [selectedColor]);
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={item => item.key}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress(item.color)} style={[styles.colorButton, { backgroundColor: item.hex, borderColor: item.color === selectedColor ? 'red' : '#ddd' }]} />
        )
      }}
      horizontal
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      removeClippedSubviews={true}
      initialNumToRender={8}
      maxToRenderPerBatch={1}
      updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100}
    />
  )
```

Product Card:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, memo } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { StyleSheet, Animated, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, TextInput, BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';
import { addCart } from '../redux/slice/product/shopping_cart';
import Product_stack_images from './FlatList/product_stack/Product_stack_images';
import { AntDesign, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Stars from './Stars';
import Choose_Color from './FlatList/product_stack/Choose_Color';
import Choose_Size from './FlatList/product_stack/Choose_Size';
import Button from './FlatList/product_stack/Button';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import { Modalize } from 'react-native-modalize';
import faker from 'faker';
import { Host, Portal } from 'react-native-portalize';
import { SnappingList } from './modal/Snapping';
import { ModalVideo } from './modal/ModalVideo';
import ButtonWithoutLoader from './ButtonWithoutLoader';
import Toast from 'react-native-toast-message';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
// const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const ProductStack = ({ route }) => {
  const { id, name, desc, username, product_image, user_profil_image, colors, size } = route.params;
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const modalizeRef = useRef(null);
  const modalizeVideoRef = useRef(null);

  /* Allow to press hardware button */
  const [allow, setAllow] = useState(1);

  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1);
  const [selectedSize, setSelectedSize] = useState(null);
  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState(null);
  
  const [show, setShow] = useState(null);

  /* Modal */
  const animated = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const modals = Array.from({ length: 8 }).map(_ => useRef(null).current);

  const profile_image = faker.image.avatar();
 
  const data = [
    {
      key: '1',
      image: 'https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/9dcd25fef3f137e7ae494758e7c52545/bd500216513b46d9bea52787ea571205.jpg?imwidth=1800&filter=packshot'
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      image: 'https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/c3a9082e42283a23ba82616f6c3a6420/403b15ca90bf4d83acb2e59646be0a77.jpg?imwidth=1800'
    }
  ];

  const dataColor = [
    {
      key: "1",
      hex: '#fff',
      color: "white"
    },
    {
      key: "2",
      hex: '#000',
      color: "black"
    },
    {
      key: "3",
      hex: '#2b80ff',
      color: "blue" // #2b80ff
    },
    {
      key: "4",
      hex: '#FF0000',
      color: "red"
    },
  ];

  const dataSize = [
    {
      key: '1',
      size: 'XS'
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      size: 'S'
    },
    {
      key: '3',
      size: 'M'
    },
    {
      key: '4',
      size: 'L'
    }
  ];

  const [m, setM] = useState(false);

  const openModalSetting = () => {
    modalizeRef.current?.open();
  };

  const handleAddCart = () => {
    setShow(prevState => !prevState);
    dispatch(addCart({
      type: 'NORMAL',
      item: {
        user_id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3),
        product_id: 1,
        product_name: 'Calvin klein Bag',
        price: 29.99,
        selectedSize,
        product_image: data[0].image,
        amount,
        username: 'Ester71',
        }
      })
    );
  };

  const handleMinusAmount = () => {
    amount > 1 && amount < 9999 && setAmount(prevState => prevState - 1);
  };

  const handleAddAmount = () => {
    amount > 0 && amount < 9999 && setAmount(prevState => prevState + 1);
  };

  console.log(selectedColor);

  return (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Host>
      <Animated.View style={{
          flex: 1,
          borderRadius: animated.interpolate({ inputRange: [0, 1], outputRange: [0, 12] }),
          transform: [
            {
              scale: animated.interpolate({ inputRange: [0, 1], outputRange: [1, 0.92] }),
            },
          ],
          opacity: animated.interpolate({ inputRange: [0, 1], outputRange: [1, 0.75] }),
        }}
      >
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled" contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1, width: '100%'}} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.container}>
          <StatusBar hidden />
          <Product_stack_images data={data} />
          <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <View style={styles.mainHeader}>
              <View style={styles.mainHeaderLeft}>
                <Text style={styles.product_name}>Calvin Klein Bag</Text>
                <Stars />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.mainHeaderRight}>
                <Text style={styles.price}>29.<Text style={{fontSize: 16}}>99€</Text></Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.optionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>Farbe</Text>
              <Choose_Color onPress={color => setSelectedColor(color)} data={dataColor} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.optionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>Größe</Text>
              <Choose_Size onPress={size => setSelectedSize(size)} data={dataSize} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.optionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>Produktbeschreibung</Text>
              <Text style={styles.product_desc}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={[styles.optionContainer, { flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 12 }]}>
              <View style={styles.shippingContainer}>
                <Ionicons name="ios-time-outline" size={24} color="#555" />
                <Text style={styles.textShippingTime}>Lieferung in 1-2 Werktagen</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.amountContainer}>
                <View style={styles.amountView}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleMinusAmount}>
                    <AntDesign name="minus" size={20} color="#555" />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <TextInput value={amount.toString()} onChangeText={e => setAmount(e)} keyboardType="numeric" style={styles.amountText} />
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleAddAmount}>
                    <AntDesign name="plus" size={20} color="#555" />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <ButtonWithoutLoader title="In den Einkaufswagen" onPress={handleAddCart} />
            </View>
          </View>
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        <Toast style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 2}} ref={(ref) => Toast.setRef(ref)} />
      </Animated.View>
    </Host>
  </View>
  )
};
```

The reason why I update in one Component setSelectedColor and in the other also setSelectedColor is, if I send directly the color from Choose_color component to Product_card, then its take also 700ms-1second so the user see the selected Color after 700ms and thats bad so I use it like this above.

The problem is now If I console.log my setSelectedColor from my Product Card file, it shows after 700ms-1sec

Comment: you may read this https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance and this https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html. generally use ```class Component extends React.PureComponent``` for class component, or ```export default React.memo(Component)``` for functional component... but it is important to read the docs

Comment: I already used memo

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making 2 calls to change the colour, I would make it just 1 in the parent component. Meaning you should move the 'handlePress' function as well as the 'selectedColor' state variable into 'Product Card. Then pass both of those through props into the 'Choose_Color' object.